# Relation between coefficients of polynomial to get real roots

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to find a relation between coefficients $a$ and $b$ of the equation $a x^3 + b x^2 - x + 2 =0$ so that I get positive real roots of the equation (i.e. $x\geq0$). Any help on how to do this on Mathematica 12?

Comment: Check the function Discriminant.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau
 Thanks I have taken the discriminant,
g[a_, b_] := Discriminant[a^2 x^3 + 2 b x^2 - x + 2, x] and done a region plot, RegionPlot[g[a, b] >= 0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}]. It solves my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 Solve[a*x^3 + b*x^2 - x + 2 == 0 && x >= 0, x, Reals]
```

You should get the roots (3) with the conditional domains for the coefficients.  The notebook will return them as icons which you can expand and examine.

Comment: +1 You could also append `//ToRadicals` or `//ToRadicals//InputForm`

Comment: Using `ToRadicals` will not readily help due to the [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - `ToRadicals` alleviates the panic that some experience when encountering `Root` expressions. In this case, the order of the polynomial is low enough that `ToRadicals` will always work to eliminate the `Root` representation.

Comment: I realize it will eliminate the `Root` expressions. The problem is that both cases of one and three real roots will be indistinguishable (ignoring the case where `a=0` and there are only two roots). That's the gist of the casus irreducibilis: the radical expressions will have explicit imaginary values even when they are real-valued....

Comment: ...Example: `In[2702]:= rads = ToRadicals[SolveValues[x^3 + -5*x^2 - x + 2 == 0, x]]
N[rads] // Chop

Out[2702]= {5/3 - (14 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/(
  3 (1/2 (241 + 9 I Sqrt[367]))^(1/3)) - 
  1/6 (1 - I Sqrt[3]) (1/2 (241 + 9 I Sqrt[367]))^(1/3), 
 5/3 - (14 (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/(3 (1/2 (241 + 9 I Sqrt[367]))^(1/3)) - 
  1/6 (1 + I Sqrt[3]) (1/2 (241 + 9 I Sqrt[367]))^(1/3), 
 1/3 (5 + 28/(1/2 (241 + 9 I Sqrt[367]))^(
    1/3) + (1/2 (241 + 9 I Sqrt[367]))^(1/3))}

Out[2703]= {-0.6874, 0.568373, 5.11903}`